# How to install a working Perl Cassandra client on alpine docker

Tags: docker, perl, cassandra, alpine-linux

Which is the best perl Cassandra client to run on Alpine docker & how do I install and use it?

Please provide a docker file or at least the docker command and a POC script that connects to Cassandra.

Here is the newest attempt to use DBD::Cassandra library the docker file actually successfully completes and get's deployed:

```
FROM alpine:3.10.3

## alpine curl and wget aren't fully compatible, so we install them
## here. gnupg is needed for Module::Signature.
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar make gcc build-base wget gnupg ca-certificates g++ git gd-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache zlib zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache perl perl-dev

RUN apk add --no-cache perl-app-cpanminus
RUN cpanm App::cpm

WORKDIR /usr

RUN cpm install Try::Tiny
RUN cpm install YAML
RUN cpm install JSON
RUN cpm install JSON::MaybeXS
RUN cpm install HTTP::Request
RUN cpm install HTTP::Response
RUN cpm install HTTP::Daemon

RUN cpm install GD::Simple
RUN cpm install GD::Graph
RUN cpm install Data::HexDump::Range
RUN cpm install Proc::Daemon
RUN cpm install Test::Block
RUN cpm install Text::Colorizer
RUN cpm install Gzip::Faster

ENV PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl5
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

RUN apk add --no-cache musl-obstack-dev --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main

RUN cpm install Proc::ProcessTable
RUN cpm install Kafka::Connection

RUN apk add --update openssl && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

#RUN cpm install DBI
RUN cpm install DBD::Cassandra

COPY run.sh /run.sh

RUN chmod +x "/run.sh"

RUN mkdir -p /code_path

WORKDIR /code_path

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

here is the script:

```
use Data::Dumper;

use DBD::Cassandra;
use DBI;

say("Mama");

my $user = undef;
my $password = undef;

my $host = 'cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local';
my $keyspace = 'grids';
my $table = 'electricity_grid';

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Cassandra:host=$host;keyspace=$keyspace", $user, $password, { RaiseError => 1 });
my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT * FROM $table");

for my $row (@$rows) {
    # Do something with your row
    say($row);
}
```

but the code example doesn't work as if the library wasn't installed:

```
bash-5.0# ./demoCassandra.pl 
Can't locate DBD/Cassandra.pm in @INC (you may need to install the 
DBD::Cassandra module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.2 /usr/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at ./demoCassandra.pl line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./demoCassandra.pl line 7.
```

This is an old attempt: I'm leving it here due to the relevance of the answer by @valiano below.

The most recent library I found is: DBD::Cassandra
So I tried to install perl DBD::Cassandra 
On alpine docker this failed:

```
cpm install DBD::Cassandra
```

after reading log I successfully installed

```
cpm install IO::Socket::INET6
```

and failed installing

```
cpm install OpenSSL
```

here is the base file:

```
FROM alpine:3.10.3


## alpine curl and wget aren't fully compatible, so we install them
## here. gnupg is needed for Module::Signature.
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar make gcc build-base wget gnupg ca-certificates g++ git gd-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache zlib zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache perl perl-dev

RUN curl -L <this was cencored by stack overflow>cpanm > /bin/cpanm && chmod +x /bin/cpanm
RUN cpanm App::cpm

WORKDIR /usr

RUN cpm install Try::Tiny
RUN cpm install YAML
RUN cpm install JSON
RUN cpm install JSON::MaybeXS
RUN cpm install HTTP::Request
RUN cpm install HTTP::Response
RUN cpm install HTTP::Daemon

RUN cpm install GD::Simple
RUN cpm install GD::Graph
RUN cpm install Data::HexDump::Range
RUN cpm install Proc::Daemon
RUN cpm install Test::Block
RUN cpm install Text::Colorizer
RUN cpm install Gzip::Faster

ENV PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl5
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

RUN apk add --no-cache musl-obstack-dev --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing

RUN cpm install Proc::ProcessTable
RUN cpm install Kafka::Connection

COPY run.sh /run.sh

RUN chmod +x "/run.sh"

RUN mkdir -p /code_path

WORKDIR /code_path

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

output fail file indicated IO::Socket::INET6 OpenSSL were missing:

```
bash-5.0# tail /root/.cpanm/work/1582818617.3526/build.log
/usr/include/openssl/bn.h:332:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_0_9_8(int
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
OpenSSL.xs: In function 'boot_OpenSSL':
OpenSSL.xs:854:9: warning: implicit declaration of function     'SSL_load_error_strings'; did you mean 'ERR_lib_error_string'? [-Wimplicit-        function-declaration]
     SSL_load_error_strings();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     ERR_lib_error_string
make: *** [Makefile:353: OpenSSL.o] Error 1
-> FAIL Installing OpenSSL failed. See     /root/.cpanm/work/1582818617.3526/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Comment: Hi, what is your base image? Could you post the failed install output?

Comment: @valiano i added the dockerfile

Comment: @RubberDuck: Can you include the `cpm` log file that makes you think that you need to install module called OpenSSL? There's no module on CPAN called OpenSSL. I suspect there's some openssl development library that you need.

Comment: @DaveCross as you bid I posted the log  http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/O/OE/OESI/OpenSSL-0.10.tar.gz

Comment: @RubberDuck: We need to see more of that log. I'd like to see the bit that tells us which module required the installation of OpenSSL. The author has apparently hidden that module from CPAN's indexes - so he obviously doesn't expect it to work. Also, it hasn't been updated for a long time, which implies it's unsupported. I wouldn't recommend using it (or anything that requires it).

Comment: @DaveCross i am in need of a Cassandra binding library in Perl and would rather not write a c++ wrapper for the Datastax library. I chose the most recent https://github.com/TvdW/perl-DBD-Cassandra If you have a better suggestion I would be gratefull

Answer (score 3):

After two days of fiddling I arrived at this dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.10.3
MAINTAINER hamshif

## alpine curl and wget aren't fully compatible, so we install them
## here. gnupg is needed for Module::Signature.
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar make gcc build-base wget gnupg ca-certificates g++ git gd-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache zlib zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache perl perl-dev

RUN apk add --no-cache perl-app-cpanminus
RUN cpanm App::cpm

WORKDIR /usr

RUN cpm install Try::Tiny
RUN cpm install YAML
RUN cpm install JSON
RUN cpm install JSON::MaybeXS
RUN cpm install HTTP::Request
RUN cpm install HTTP::Response
RUN cpm install HTTP::Daemon

RUN cpm install GD::Simple
RUN cpm install GD::Graph
RUN cpm install Data::HexDump::Range
RUN cpm install Proc::Daemon
RUN cpm install Test::Block
RUN cpm install Text::Colorizer
RUN cpm install Gzip::Faster

ENV PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl5
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

RUN apk add --no-cache musl-obstack-dev --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main

RUN cpm install Proc::ProcessTable
RUN cpm install Kafka::Connection

RUN apk add --update openssl

RUN apk add --update openssl-dev

RUN cpm install IO::Socket::INET6
RUN cpm install Net::SSLeay

#RUN cpm install Cassandra::Client

RUN cpm install https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/T/TV/TVDW/Cassandra-Client-0.10.tar.gz

RUN cpm install DBI
RUN cpm install DBD::Cassandra && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY run.sh /run.sh

RUN chmod +x "/run.sh"

RUN mkdir -p /code_path

WORKDIR /code_path

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

This script worked in the docker (on kubernetes desktop):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature qw/say/;
use Data::Dumper;

use XSLoader;
use Cassandra::Client;
use DBD::Cassandra;
use DBI;

say("Mama");

my $user = undef;
my $password = undef;

my $host = 'cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local';
my $keyspace = 'grids';
my $table = 'electricity_grid';

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Cassandra:host=$host;keyspace=$keyspace", $user, $password, { RaiseError => 1 });
my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT * FROM $table");

for my $row (@$rows) {
    # Do something with your row
    say($row);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully build the attached Dockerfile, using the following adjustments:

- For `/bin/cpanm`, using Alpine's native package, [perl-app-cpanminus](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.10/community/x86_64/perl-app-cpanminus):

  `RUN apk add --no-cache perl-app-cpanminus`

  (rather than manually downloading the `cpanm` binary - is it a special custom build?)
- [musl-obstack-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/musl-obstack-dev) has relocated from `edge/testing` to the `edge/main` repository:

  `RUN apk add --no-cache musl-obstack-dev --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main`

Comment: @valino your changes work but do not enable installing the Cassandra library. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RubberDuck Could you elaborate on the failure and post the failed install output?

Comment: @valino I added above a second attempt where the docker file gets built but doesn't seem to be added to the path